# Rails uninitialized constant error with mount_uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, scaffolding

I am using **Rails scaffold** to create a simple model called **`Movies`** that contains the movie's `name`, `director`, `synopsis` and `poster`.

I am using the **Carrierwave** gem to upload the poster image. When I first boot up the rails server, I get the following message:

> NameError in MoviesController#new
>
> uninitialized constant Movie::PosterUploader

The extracted source the error screen displays is my `models/movie.rb` file:

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :poster, PosterUploader
end
```

**Here is my movies controller:**

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_movie, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /movies
  # GET /movies.json
  def index
    @movies = Movie.all
 end

  # GET /movies/1
  # GET /movies/1.json
  def show
  end

   # GET /movies/new
  def new
    @movie = Movie.new
  end

  # GET /movies/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /movies
  # POST /movies.json
  def create
    @movie = Movie.new(movie_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @movie.save
        format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Movie was successfully 
created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @movie }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @movie.errors, status: 
:unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /movies/1
  # PATCH/PUT /movies/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @movie.update(movie_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Movie was successfully 
updated.' }
         format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @movie }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @movie.errors, status: 
:unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /movies/1
  # DELETE /movies/1.json
  def destroy
    @movie.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to movies_url, notice: 'Movie was successfully 
destroyed.' }
       format.json { head :no_content }
    end
   end

   private
     # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
     def set_movie
      @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
     end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white 
list through.
    def movie_params
      params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :director, :synopsis, :poster)
    end
end
```

When I created the model using Rails scaffold I made the poster a string, but changed that to file in this section of Movies form partial:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :poster %>
    <%= form.file_field :poster, id: :movie_poster %>
  </div>
```

Here is my `routes` file just in case I have made an error there:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :movies
  root 'movies#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> uninitialized constant Movie::PosterUploader

You should **generate** the *uploader*. Do

```
rails generate uploader Poster
```

which should generate the file

```
app/uploaders/poster_uploader.rb
```

Comment: @glad to help :) Accept my answer.